# oracle before update trigger failed

Tags: sql, oracle

I created an audit trigger on oracle database to track some changes like this

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name 
after UPDATE  
ON table_name 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (:old.table_name,:new.table_name,sysdate);
delete from mytable where column_date+30>sysdate;


END; 
/
```

i wanted the data for only one month so i used the code:

```
delete from mytable where column_date+30> sysdate;
```

the trigger was working for fine and suddenly the update on the table stopped.
i tried to add exception like:

```
EXCEPTION  
WHEN OTHERS THEN
null;
```

but it did not work so i had to drop the trigger.
so what is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean with " the update on the table stopped"? Please post an example of what you did, trying to better explain the issue: are you having an error, an unexpected behaviour, ... ? You also may want to have a look at [mcve]

Comment: The delete would be more efficient (i.e. it can use an index) if you change the where clause to `where column_date > sysdate - 30`

Comment: @Mohamed Elsaba: It will be more efficient ,if you write the delete statement on `statement level trigger` rather than row level trigger.And it will be better if you log exception to see somewhere

Comment: " the update on the table stopped" means i had an error unable to update the table